# Manually entered products not showing in upsells etc?

Tags: product, magento-1.9, cross-sells, up-sells

New Magento install, and we are entering products manually at this point. 
All products are simple products and they are showing fine on the site when you go shopping.

However, when I am in the back end and trying to configure the products to have upsells, related products and cross-sells, there are no products appearing in those boxes.

Why would this be???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Up sell grid]

The first column on the left hand side will be set to yes by default. Set this to no or empty and it should display all products. By default this grid filters out all products that haven't been set to upsell yet.